# Display content based on Author Custom Post type

Tags: custom-post-types, conditional-content, author-template

I have 2 forms. Form A creates a new user with the role of Author and also creates an entry in a CPT called Judges.

Form B creates a new user also with the role of Author and creates an entry in a CPT called Submissions.

So if both forms are submitted we have 2 new users both with the same role of Author, one has created a Judge entry, the other a Submissions entry.

On author.php I need to show the personal info like name, email etc. Now, I also need to display those forms again and query some other CPT info. The problem is, how can I show Author A the judge form and only content related to CPT judges, and Author B the Submissions form and only content related to CPT Submissions.

Ive been trying to use something like this as a start.

```
<?php if( get_post_type() == 'judges' ) { //start CPT conditional ?>

<?php } elseif ( get_post_type() == 'submissions' ) { ?>

<?php } //end CPT conditional ?>
```

Comment: Can you more precise about your conditional checks? get_post_type() would require an ID in your case (I think). Do you supply that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the description of your issue it sounds like there is one key piece of information missing. When the form is submitted you need to insert a custom meta value in wp_usermeta that will create a relationship between the new user and the corresponding custom post type. Lets call it meta_key = 'user_post_id' for the code example below.

This custom meta value can then be used on your author.php page to handle the split logic you mentioned above:

```
<?php
// get the 'user_post_id' from the 'wp_usermeta' table
$post_id = get_user_meta($user_id, 'user_post_id', true);

// start the split logic
if( get_post_type($post_id) == 'judges' ) { /* judges code goes here */ }
elseif( get_post_type() == 'submissions' ) { /* submissions code goes here */ }
?>
```

As an alternative to creating a relationship to a specific post, you could just set a 'user_type' meta key with a value of either 'judges' or 'submissions'. In that case the code would adjust as so:

```
<?php
// get the 'user_type' from the 'wp_usermeta' table
$user_type = get_user_meta($user_id, 'user_type', true);

// start the split logic
if( $user_type == 'judges' ) { /* judges code goes here */ }
elseif( $user_type == 'submissions' ) { /* submissions code goes here */ }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I am using Gravity forms which has an ID stored as post metadata for each entry so was able to use that along with your code.